# How do I type a tabulation character on an Xperia?

Tags: keyboard, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10

I imported my notes from my Palm Centro into [Note Everything](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.softxperience.android.noteeverything) and the tab characters in my existing notes show up correctly.

But how do I type a tab character on my Xperia X10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use [the Swype keyboard](http://beta.swype.com/), holding the space key gives you a tab.  [Smart Keyboard Pro](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.cdeguet.smartkeyboardpro) also has tab, press `?123` twice for it.

Reference: http://androidforums.com/android-applications/151563-softkeyboard-tab-key.html

Comment: Didn't know that about the Swype keyboard (not that I use tab often).

Comment: I installed Smart Keyboard but didn't find any key for tabulation. Is it only available in the Pro version?

Comment: Smart Keyboard Pro is the right answer. It also has arrow keys, so now I don't need to post a second question about that. :-)

Answer (score 5):

On the stock keyboard on my Droid (the soft keyboard, not the slide-out) I see the tab character on the alt-symbol keyboard.

Hit <kbd>?123</kbd> key, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>. The tab key looks like an arrow pointing right to a line.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't present on X10. :-/