# Android keyboard - Tab into next form field?

Tags: keyboard

I'm using a tablet with Android 2.2. Is there something like <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to the next form field?

Comment: Closely related, if not a duplicate: [How do I type a tabulation character on an Xperia?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/8235)

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean with an external keyboard or the on-screen keyboard?

With the on-screen keyboard, usually the `<Enter>` key turns into a `<Next>` key (looks like a right arrow) when there is another field after the current one. At least, this seems to be how most apps on Android work.

Sometimes it doesn't change functionality; this happens most often in web forms where the enter key is a valid input.

Comment: That doesn't work when the field is  a textarea (multi-lines).  The <enter> key inserts a newline.

Answer (score 4):

If you have [SWYPE](http://www.swype.com/), all you need to do is long press the SPACE bar.

Alternatively, you can download [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) from the Play Store. It has `TAB/CTRL/ESC/ARROW` keys etc